# How to convert HTML to text without tags and special characters?

Tags: javascript, html, string

I have a series of quotes that look like this:

```
<p>Being a graphic designer gets you used to rejection of your brilliance. So it&#8217;s good practice for dating.  </p>
```

I would like them to look like this:

```
 Being a graphic designer gets you used to rejection of your brilliance. So it's good practice for dating.
```

I tried using innerHTML, with limited success.

Comment: innerhtml fetches the html, obviously. try `innerText`

Comment: _"I would like them to look like this"_ Not certain what you are trying to achieve? The first example should render `'` as text appears to be enclosed in `<p>` element?

Answer (score 3):

Create a temporary   span element with the html content as string using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) method. Later get the text content by getting the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)  property.

```js
var str = '<p>Being a graphic designer gets you used to rejection of your brilliance. So it&#8217;s good practice for dating.  </p>';

// create a span element
var temp = document.createElement('span');
// set the html to the element
temp.innerHTML = str;
// get the text content
console.log(temp.textContent);
```

Comment: I tried it on a JSON string, it does not work... it returns undefined